# Collision Detection Operations using a Vector3f in Java

Tags: java, collision, physics-engine

I want to start doing collision detection calculations in Java using my Vector3f Class.
However, the assignment statement for **centerDistance** (see code below) gives off the error: `The operator - is undefined for the argument type (Vector3f)`.
I guess at my skill level, I just can't quite figure out what the issue is. Does anyone out there maybe have a clue?

```
public class BoundingSphere {

    private Vector3f m_center;
    private float m_radius;

    public BoundingSphere(Vector3f center, float radius) {
        this.m_center = center;
        this.m_radius = radius;
    }

    public IntersectData IntersectBoundingSphere(BoundingSphere other) {
        float radiusDistance = m_radius + other.m_radius;
        float centerDistance = (other.getM_center() - m_center).length();
        float distance = centerDistance - radiusDistance;

        return IntersectData(centerDistance < radiusDistance, distance);
    }

    public Vector3f getM_center() {
        return m_center;
    }

    public void setM_center(Vector3f m_center) {
        this.m_center = m_center;
    }

    public float getM_radius() {
        return m_radius;
    }

    public void setM_radius(float m_radius) {
        this.m_radius = m_radius;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects do not support arithmetic operators in Java. You must make a method for add, subtract, etc.

example:

```
public Vector3f add(Vector3f operand) { 
    //...
    return this;
}

public Vector3f sub(Vector3f operand) { 
    //...
    return this;
}
```

then you call `other.getM_center().sub(m_center).length()`

Comment: If this is the correct answer please accept it by pressing the checkmark under this answer's vote count.